# SQL. Select Unixtime for whole day

Tags: sql, sqlite, unix, time

I am looking for a way to select a whole days worth of data from a where statement. Timestamp is in unix time such as (1406045122). I want to select the today's date of unix time range and find all the food that has been added in today. Thank in advance. This is the code I wrote. I'm not sure what I should put in the ( ????? ) part. I know it has to do with 60*60*24=86400 secs per day but I'm not too sure how I can implement this.

```
Select timestamp,food from table1 where timestamp = ( ????? );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select timestamp,food 
FROM table1 
WHERE timestamp > :ts 
  AND timestamp <= (:ts + 86400);
```

replace :ts with the starting timstamp and you'll filter a whole day's worth of data

### edit

This select query would give you the current timestamp (there may be more efficient ones, i don't work with sqlite often)

```
select strftime("%s", current_timestamp);
```

You can find more info about them here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm

Using the strftime() function, combined with the date() function we can write this following query which will not need any manual editing. It will return the records filtered on timestamp > start of today & timestamp <= end of today.

```
Select timestamp,food 
FROM table1 
WHERE timestamp > strftime("%s", date(current_timestamp)) 
  AND timestamp <= (strftime("%s", date(current_timestamp)) + 86400);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to grab ts automatically within the script ? I prefer not to manually go into the script every single day.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage will likely depend on your version of SQL but for example on MySQL you can specify a search as being `BETWEEN` two dates, which is taken conventionally to mean midnight on each. So

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE T BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-02';
```

selects anything with a timestamp anywhere on 1st July 2014. If you want to make it readable you could even use the ADDDATE function. So you could do something like

```
SET @mydate = DATE(T);
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE T BETWEEN @mydate AND ADDDATE(@mydate, 1);
```

The first line should truncate your timestamp to be 00:00:00. The second line should `SELECT` only records from that date.